# MySQL query with JOIN and GROUP BY optimization. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables: gpnxuser and key_value

```
mysql> describe gpnxuser;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version      | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uuid         | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| partner_id   | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| password     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
mysql> describe key_value;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| upkey          | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id        | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| security_level | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

key_value.user_id is FK that references gpnxuser.id. I also have an index in gpnxuser.partner_id which is a FK that references a table called "partner" (which, I think, does not matter much to this question).

For partner_id = 64, I have 500K rows in gpnxuser which have relationship with approximatelly 6M rows in key_value.

I wanted to have a query that returned all distinct 'key_value.upkey' for user´s belonging to a given partner. I did something like this:

```
select upkey from gpnxuser join key_value on gpnxuser.id=key_value.user_id where partner_id=64 group by upkey;
```

which takes forever to run. The explain for the query looks like:

```
mysql> explain select upkey from gpnxuser join key_value on gpnxuser.id=key_value.user_id where partner_id=64 group by upkey;

    +----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref                         | rows   | Extra                                        |
    +----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | gpnxuser  | ref  | PRIMARY,FKB2D9FEBE725C505E | FKB2D9FEBE725C505E | 8       | const                       | 259640 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | key_value | ref  | FK9E0C0F912D11F5A9         | FK9E0C0F912D11F5A9 | 9       | gpnx_finance_db.gpnxuser.id |     14 | Using where                                  |
    +----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

My question is: is there a query that can run fast and obtain the result that I want?

Comment: It looks like the best place for this question is: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is utilize **EXISTS** statement: This will cause only partial table scan until a match found and not more.

```
select upkey from (select distinct upkey from key_value) upk 
where EXISTS 
    (select 1 from gpnxuser u, key_value kv 
     where u.id=kv.user_id and partner_id=1 and kv.upkey = upk.upkey)
```

NB. In the original query, **group by** is misused: **distinct** looks better there.

```
select DISTINCT upkey from gpnxuser join key_value on 
gpnxuser.id=key_value.user_id where partner_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into partitioning your `key_value` table on `user_id`, if you typically run queries based on this column.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html